# Global variable not populated correctly from aggregated filter variables

Tags: rundeck, pagerduty

We are currently running Rundeck 4.11 community version.
We are having problems using aggregated log filter variables.

Example:

Job1 runs a command step against three nodes (Keep running if failed)
The command returns one line of stdout per node.

Job1 has a log filter that captures all output from previous step.

```
Regex: ^(.*)$     Name: output
```

Job1 runs a global variable step that sets an exportable variable from previous variable, for all nodes.

```
all_output=${data.output*}
```

Job2 starts by running Job1 as a referenced job (using referenced nodes)

Job2 runs a command locally to print all output from the global variable set in Job1.

```
echo "${export.all_output}"
```

Expected behaviour:
Comma separated list of all output (from all nodes) from the first step of Job1 regardless of state of job.

Examined behaviour:

If Job1-Step1 is successful on all nodes, all output is printed.

If Job1-Step1 is unsuccessful (rc > 0) on all nodes, all output is printed.

If some nodes fail on Job1-Step1 and some are successful, only failed nodes output is printed.

If rundeck can not connect to at least one node, only the literal text ${export.all_output} is printed, and variable is not expanded at all. Another run expanded the variable, but it was empty.

It seems that the global log filter, and use of data.output* (note the star), is dependent on the status of steps/jobs, and is not purely printing everything the log filter captures.

Here are two jobs that reproduce the issue. This basically runs a command on each node and exits randomly with 0 or 1. Only the failed nodes' data is captured. Just modify the filter so it will run in your environment.

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  group: aggregate
  id: 0d50e127-7017-4319-8b56-3fd56080e5a3
  loglevel: INFO
  name: test
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: true
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'tags: linux'
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: ((RANDOM % 2)) && { echo "${node.name} OK"; exit 0; } || { echo "${node.name}
        NOT OK"; exit 1;  }
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'false'
            name: full_command_output
            regex: ^(.*)$
            replaceFilteredResult: 'false'
          type: key-value-data
    - configuration:
        export: aggregated_output
        group: export
        value: ${data.full_command_output*;}
      nodeStep: false
      type: export-var
    keepgoing: true
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 0d50e127-7017-4319-8b56-3fd56080e5a3

- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  group: aggregate
  id: d888974d-7dee-4d55-9afa-fa529a0d968b
  loglevel: INFO
  name: aggtest
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: MyServer
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - jobref:
        childNodes: true
        group: aggregate
        name: test
        nodeStep: 'true'
        uuid: 0d50e127-7017-4319-8b56-3fd56080e5a3
    - configuration:
        command: 'echo ''''''Aggregated Output: ${export.aggregated_output}'''''''
      nodeStep: true
      type: localexec
    keepgoing: true
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: d888974d-7dee-4d55-9afa-fa529a0d968b
```

Comment: Hi! Could you share a reproducible example job defintion to take a look? thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I have added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior on the latest Rundeck version, please report it [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).

Anyway, I found a workaround using a temporary working file. Basically, is about replacing the export variable by an local file.

Let me share the jobs (tested on Rundeck 4.14.1).

Parent job:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: d888974d-7dee-4d55-9afa-fa529a0d968b
  loglevel: INFO
  name: parent
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'name: node00 '
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - jobref:
        childNodes: true
        group: ''
        name: child
        nodeStep: 'true'
        uuid: 0d50e127-7017-4319-8b56-3fd56080e5a3
    - configuration:
        command: /bin/bash -c 'cat myfile; rm myfile'
      nodeStep: true
      type: localexec
    keepgoing: true
    strategy: sequential
  uuid: d888974d-7dee-4d55-9afa-fa529a0d968b
```

Child job:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 0d50e127-7017-4319-8b56-3fd56080e5a3
  loglevel: INFO
  name: child
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: true
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'tags: myservers'
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: ((RANDOM % 2)) && { echo "${node.name} OK"; exit 0; } || { echo "${node.name}
        NOT OK"; exit 1;  }
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'false'
            name: mydata
            regex: ^(.*)$
            replaceFilteredResult: 'false'
          type: key-value-data
    - configuration:
        command: /bin/bash -c 'echo ${data.mydata} >> myfile'
      nodeStep: true
      type: localexec
    keepgoing: true
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 0d50e127-7017-4319-8b56-3fd56080e5a3
```

Check the result [here](https://imgur.com/ox0KpHh).

Comment: Thanks for the workaraound @MegaDrive68. I have reported the issue.